# ColorBox: Box Sizing too small, still has content to display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

My ColorBox is sizing too small when it appears on the screen, even though there's still content for it to display. Any ideas why?

Link is: (I  think it works externally...if not let me know...)
 http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/

The box pops up when you first load the website. The cookies are set to expire at 30 days.

I just need the box to actually show its' content, not give me scroll bars on the sides. I was looking through the CSS, and I couldn't find anything that's doing that.

As you can see in my image:

[image]

It's just showing the scroll bars on the right hand side, instead of showing my content. Doesn't make much sense to me.

HTML/JavaScript:

```
<script>

$("document").ready(function (){ 

   // load the overlay

    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
        var thirtyDays = 1000*60*60*24*30;
        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + thirtyDays);
        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        $.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
    }

    $(".open_popup").colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});

 });


</script>

<!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls for the subscribe box -->
<div style='display:none'>
  <div id='subscribe_popup' style='padding:10px;'>
    <div align="center" style="width:525px"><img src="http://www.amleo.com/images/art/Survey_ad.jpg" style="width:525px"/></div>
    <div align="center">Please enter your e-mail address below to sign up.</div>
    <!-- BEGIN #subs-container -->
    <div id="subs-container" class="clearfix">
      <!-- BEGIN .box-side -->
      <div>
            <form name="box-form" id="box-form" method="post" action="http://www.gliq.com/cgi-bin/subunsub" style="margin-top: -9px; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;width:177px;">
            <input name="email" size=20>
            <input type="hidden" name="acctname" value="amleo">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
            <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://www.amleo.com/subscribesuccessful/a/47/">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" style="margin-left:45px;">
        </form>
        <!-- END .box-side -->
      </div>
      <!-- BEGIN #subs-container -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END subscribe popup-->
```

CSS:

```
/*
    ColorBox Core Style:
    The following CSS is consistent between example themes and should not be altered.
*/
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:visible;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}

/* 
    User Style:
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of ColorBox.  They are
    ordered & tabbed in a way that represents the nesting of the generated HTML.
*/
#cboxOverlay{background:#000;opacity:0.3 !important;}
#colorbox{
background-color:#333;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
        }

    #cboxTopLeft{width:14px; height:14px;}
    #cboxTopCenter{height:14px;}
    #cboxTopRight{width:14px; height:14px;}
    #cboxBottomLeft{width:14px; height:43px;}
    #cboxBottomCenter{height:43px;}
    #cboxBottomRight{width:14px; height:43px; }
    #cboxMiddleLeft{width:14px;}
    #cboxMiddleRight{width:14px;}
    #cboxContent{overflow:visible;}
    #cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:5px;}
    #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:url(http://www.amleo.com/images/art/boxloading_background.png) no-repeat center center;}
    #cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(http://www.amleo.com/images/art/boxloading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
    #cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:-25px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; font-weight:bold; color:#7C7C7C;}
    #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:-25px; left:58px; font-weight:bold; color:#7C7C7C;}

    #cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{position:absolute; bottom:-29px; background:url(http://www.amleo.com/images/art/boxcontrols.png) no-repeat 0px 0px; width:23px; height:23px; text-indent:-9999px;}
    #cboxPrevious{left:0px; background-position: -51px -25px;}
    #cboxPrevious.hover{background-position:-51px 0px;}
    #cboxNext{left:27px; background-position:-75px -25px;}
    #cboxNext.hover{background-position:-75px 0px;}
    #cboxClose{right:0; background-position:-100px -25px; border:0;}
    #cboxClose.hover{background-position:-100px 0px;border:0;}

    .cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow{background-position:-125px 0px; right:27px;}
    .cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow.hover{background-position:-150px 0px;}
    .cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow{background-position:-150px -25px; right:27px;}
    .cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow.hover{background-position:-125px 0px;}
```

Using the latest version of ColorBox & jQuery 1.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to get rid of scroll bars and want to show all your content in the popup.

My suggestions

1. Increasing height/width of #subscribe_popup in CSS might help
2. using "overflow: hidden" for #subscribe_popup in CSS might help

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> This is likely due to IMG elements in the loaded markup having not
>   fully finished downloading before ColorBox measures the content to
>   determine the width and height it should use. The second time ColorBox
>   is opened, the images have been cached and will take up the correct
>   width and height within your document. This can easily be fixed by
>   adding the width and height dimensions to the IMG element (a
>   recommended practice), or by setting a style that specifies the width
>   and height of the image in your CSS.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq#faq-img